# Why i don't have common default gateway and dns of 192.168.1.1

Tags: networking, centos-7

I cannot open some websites(example `speedtest.net`) it takes me to the address http://1xx.1xx.2xx.4x/AirtelDSL. where **Airtel** is my service provider(ISP)

while i can open succesfully `http://speedof.me/`

my router summary shows different ip than what is shown on my PC

[image]

while my router summary has this :

[image]

Can some one explain why these two are difernet?
I was thinking there should be only one default route  and dns even on router summary i.e 192.168.1.1

I wan to do port forwarding on a non standard port to access my PC through internet over ssh  but i am failing to do so

Comment: Well your first picture shows your PCs configuration. The default-route is the next-hop address - in this case it is the IP Adress of the **LAN Interface of your router (192.168.1.1)**. Your second picture shows the **WAN-Port**  configuration of your **Router** - and this interface sends traffic to the 122.XYZ.XYZ.XYZ adress as default (your ISP IP Adress). They are 2 different interfaces.

Comment: Not just two different interfaces, but interfaces on two different networks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "WAN" configuration of your Internet box is on the ISP's side, the Internet side of the box. Your computer however is on the "LAN" side, aka the home side of the box.

Now, the default Gateway and DNS settings are two things completely different.

---

**Default Gateway** (also called router): the device a computer will ask when it tries to reach a computer on another network. Think of it as a door in a wall. The rooms are the networks, the door is the router. It has two labels, one on each side (one IP address per network it is connected to).

On your side, the box has an IP of `192.168.1.1` and on your ISP's side, it has the "WAN IP Address" in your WAN status screen . Note that IPs on your side of the box are local, as such, they can't be seen from the outside.

The gateway in WAN status is the door that allows your box to see outside of your ISP's network.

---

**DNS** (short for Domain Name Services): The system that allows your computer to translate a human readable name (like `superuser.com`) into a machine-understandable IP address (like `151.101.1.69`). Now, in most home network configurations, the DNS server used is the ISP's DNS server. On most recent boxes, the box itself acts as a DNS intermediate, which is why it sets itself as your DNS.

The fact that you can't access Speedtest is most likely a DNS problem. Contact your ISP or [use another DNS](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS).

---

As for your port forwarding issue, here's what you have to do:

1. Set up the port forwarding: any outside port to port 22 on your PC's local IP
2. From the outside, connect to your box's **WAN IP** (as seen in WAN status screen) on the "outside port" you choose when setting up port forwarding. Don't use the computer's local IP.

Comment: Thanks, very clear to me know when you make thing so simple to understand.I tried to configure my router using non 22 port( high port above 50000) but it wasn't working. I was asuming that somehwre it it blocked by firewall somewhere .Is this happening because My ISP has blocked default ssh port and i can't do anything about it

Comment: [Try using a lower port number.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Dynamic.2C_private_or_ephemeral_ports). From the same article, avoid using port numbers below 1024. As for "blocking the default SSH port", this port (port 22) is used only on your side of the box, so yous ISP has nothing to say about it.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible your ISP simply blocks the website speedtest.net. When doing a speedtest, it will download and upload lots of data as fast as it possibly can. This generates bandwidth. They may want to prevent you from doing so and redirect speedtest.net to their own site.

It may also be that they do this because they know they cannot guarantee fast speeds and thus try to prevent their users from finding out how bad it really is. Yes, I know this is bad practice, but it has happened before.

Comment: it could be, i am not getting the promised speed of 16 mbps anyway:-)

Comment: @munish i believe that you aren't confused between 16 mbps and 16 MBps :(

Comment: no i remember that,  Airtel was good/relaible before but now beacuse of lot of competetion from others providing cheap fast internet at the same rate.they are not the same anymore